# AngularJS controller injection coffee script generation error

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm trying to understand why the following coffeescript generates a javascript with puts the statement referencing the $resource variable outside the function scope.

Coffee script :

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
controllers.controller("UsersController", [ '$scope', '$routeParams',
'$resource',   ($scope,$routeParams,$resource)->    Recipe =
$resource('/recipes/:recipeId', { recipeId: "@id", format: 'json' })
    Recipe.query(keywords: $routeParams.keywords, (results)->
$scope.recipes = results)

])
```

Generated code :

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

  controllers.controller("UsersController", [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', '$resource', function($scope, $routeParams, $resource) {}, Recipe = $resource('/recipes/:recipeId',
{
      recipeId: "@id",
      format: 'json'
    }), Recipe.query({
      keywords: $routeParams.keywords
    }, function(results) {
      return $scope.recipes = results;
    })   ]);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Please, instead of "quoting", try to format your code as `code`

Comment: Can explain what the problem you are seeing is?  I can't understand what you mean in the opening paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coffeescript as formatted in your question is invalid (I get an unmatched OUTDENT error). Using the formatting below produces the correct result:

**CoffeeScript:**

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
controllers.controller("UsersController", [ '$scope', '$routeParams','$resource', ($scope,$routeParams,$resource) -> 
    Recipe = $resource('/recipes/:recipeId', { recipeId: "@id", format: 'json' })
    Recipe.query(keywords: $routeParams.keywords, (results)-> $scope.recipes = results)
])
```

**Generated JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
  var controllers;

  controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

  controllers.controller("UsersController", [
'$scope', '$routeParams', '$resource', function($scope, $routeParams, $resource) {
      var Recipe;
      Recipe = $resource('/recipes/:recipeId', {
        recipeId: "@id",
        format: 'json'
      });
      return Recipe.query({
        keywords: $routeParams.keywords
      }, function(results) {
        return $scope.recipes = results;
      });
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```